# SpringMVC sending JSON data to the server (java)

Tags: java, json, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a **javascript** array which i populate with elements the array structure is :

```
 var citizens1 = [{"startLat":null,"startLng":null,"socialSecurityNumber":null}];
```

The array gets data however i need to push this data to the server for processing. The array holds **500 records**. Instead of making 500 **Web Service request** to the server i convert the array data to **JSON** string and pass all the data to the server where i process all the records at once thus making one **ajax call**.

I am not sure if i am passing the data correctly to the server. I am experiencing errors. Under is my code:

**Javascript**

```
 citizens1.push({startLat:marker[index].getPosition().lat(),startLng:marker[index].getPosition().lng(),socialSecurityNumber:global_citizens[index].socialSecurityNumber});

 if(citizens1.length == 500){            
     console.log('500 records saved');          
     window.clearTimeout( timerHandle);

     for(var i = 0; i < citizens1.length ; i++){
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(citizens1);
        //console.log(myJsonString);

         //console.log(citizens1[i].lat +',' +citizens1[i].lng+','+citizens1[i].socialSecurityNumber); 
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'logMovement.htm',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                cache: false, 
                data:myJsonString,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){

                    if (data == false){
                        console.log('error occured in logging data');
                    }

                }

            });          

     }

     citizens1 = [];
 }
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="logMovement.htm", method={RequestMethod.POST},produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
     public @ResponseBody Movement logMovement(@RequestBody Movement movement)throws Exception{

         logger.info("About to log movement");

         JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(movement);
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

         List<Movement> move = mapper.readValue(jsonObj.toString(), new TypeReference<Movement>(){});

        logger.info(move);
        return null;

         /*if((!lat.equals(null)) || (!(lat == null)) || (!(lat.length() == 0))){
             double dLat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
             double dLng = Double.parseDouble(lng);
             int iSocialSecurityNumber = Integer.parseInt(socialSecurityNumber);

             this.markerManager.logMovement(dLat, dLng, iSocialSecurityNumber);

         }*/


     }
```

**Movement Class**

```
public class Movement implements Serializable{

    private List<Integer>socialSecurityNumber;
    private List<Double> startLat;
    private List<Double> startLng;
    /**
     * @param socialSecurityNumber
     * @param startLat
     * @param startLng
     */

    public Movement(){}

    public Movement(List<Integer> socialSecurityNumber, List<Double> startLat,
            List<Double> startLng) {
        super();
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
        this.startLat = startLat;
        this.startLng = startLng;
    }
//getters and setters
```

**Sample of Json Data Posted to Server**

I am seeing the first rows is 'null' i am not sure if this is causing the problem

[{"startLat":null,"startLng":null,"socialSecurityNumber":null},{"startLat":10.537749449700717,"startLng":-61.44420048947677,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.537208514171011,"startLng":-61.443589321013235,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.536667622323245,"startLng":-61.44297811322531,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.536131483465244,"startLng":-61.442362603115384,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.53566878133931,"startLng":-61.44168979108997,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.535227295591238,"startLng":-61.441000943386825,"socialSecurityNumber":198501012},{"startLat":10.170058041417015,"startLng":-61.67893982108137,"socialSecurityNumber":194302025}

**Error**

I was looking at this **SO** question which dealt with the issue [Required JSON parameter is not present in jQuery Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976316/required-json-parameter-is-not-present-in-jquery-datatables)

**`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.crimetrack.business.Movement out of START_ARRAY token`**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.crimetrack.business.Movement out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@72f1db9d; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.crimetrack.business.Movement out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@72f1db9d; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.crimetrack.business.Movement out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@72f1db9d; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeUsingCreator(BeanDeserializer.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1282)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:941)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:124)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Declare the parameter in the controller as a `String` instead of a `JSON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, the values on the left hand side of the colon need to be Strings.

```
[
    {
        "lat": null,
        "lng": null,
        "socialSecurityNumber": null
    }
]
```

Also, you appear to be using the wrong annotation, `@RequestBody` is used to parse the contents of the JSON rather than `@RequestParam` which is used to get variables from a paramter like

`?var=1&newvar=2`

Also, in your javascript, `change data:{'myData':myJsonString }` to just `data:myJsonString,`

You should make a dumb object to populate, check out this tutorial at the bottom of the page where they populate a dumb Person object [hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java)

Comment: This should be changed where in the ajax request ? what about the controller should changes be made there?

Comment: The controller looks ok although I'd have expected it to be some dumb object you were populating rather than `net.sf.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: if i populate an object how do i assign the data to that object?

Comment: This should be part of Springs JSON translation in 3.2.

Comment: Is  public void logMovement(@RequestBody String myData)throws Exception{ accurate?

Comment: Could you ask the new errors as a different question, just so it's easier to follow and you'd get more response from other SO users.

Comment: I have seen many times the moderates penalize me for asking new questions when i had a related open question. They have always advised me on restructuring the open question. Sorry for making it difficult. I just found a solution i will be posting it. Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: Thanks man you did point out to me some good stuff however i didn't want to accept your answer immediately and then others errors comes up and i needed advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can write response in the controller like this

hope this "ll be helpful

```
    //get "hie" string from the service class, String is in JSON format
    String hie = svc.getHierarchysvc();

    response.setContentType("application/json");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(hie);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to the movement class and the controller and this provided me with the solution. Under is the code for those whom may be interested in solving this error:

**Movement.java**

It is very important to have the default constructor. If this is not there json will throw errors related to **application/json; charset=utf-8** not supported http 415 unsupported media.

```
public class Movement implements Serializable{

    private int socialSecurityNumber;
    private double startLat;
    private double startLng;
    /**
     * @param socialSecurityNumber
     * @param startLat
     * @param startLng
     */

    public Movement(){}
    /**
     * @param socialSecurityNumber
     * @param startLat
     * @param startLng
     */
    public Movement(int socialSecurityNumber, double startLat, double startLng) {
        super();
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
        this.startLat = startLat;
        this.startLng = startLng;
    }
//getters and setters
```

**Controller**

Since its an array of data it is important to define the `@RequestBody` to use a **List**. Also declaring a **JSONArray** is important to hold the list. Once that have been done you can *'get'* the data based on its type. Under is the code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="logMovement.htm", method = {RequestMethod.POST},consumes = "application/json")
     public @ResponseBody Movement logMovement(@RequestBody List<Movement> movement)throws Exception{

         logger.info("About to log movement");

         JSONArray nameArray =(JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(movement);

         System.out.println(nameArray.size());

          for(Object js : nameArray){
              JSONObject json = (JSONObject)js;
              //System.out.println(json.get("socialSecurityNumber"));
              if((!json.get("startLat").equals(null))){     

                     this.markerManager.logMovement(json.getDouble("startLat"),json.getDouble("startLng"), json.getInt("socialSecurityNumber"));

                }
          }


        return null;    

     }
```